# What do you apply auto layout constraints to line up labels with background image elements?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

See the screenshot below for the example but here is the issue. I have 3 text labels and I'm trying to line those labels up with 3 circles that are part of an Image View. It appears the issue is caused when the image is set to Aspect Fit and gets scaled along with the various iPhone sizes. I can align the text labels horizontally but I cannot figure out how to set the vertical constraints to "scale" properly. Any suggestions or direction would be awesome, thanks!

[image]

Comment: It would probably be much simpler to slice up  your background image and have the circles as separate UIImageViews.

Comment: Hmm, I like that suggestion for sure. I'm curious if there's an answer using constraints but I'll likely just slice up the image. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting constant for your vertical constraint? Try to set the vertical constraint against the height of the view. One way to achieve this is to set the `Center horizontally` constraint and change the multiplier to 1.8 or something that suits.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "set the vertical constraint against the height of the view". Do you mean the height of the text label? The height of the Image View? I know how to set a multiplier, just not sure exactly _where_ you're suggesting I set it. I've tried using a multiplier in a few spots but it always seems to _really_ throw things out of whack but I'm likely just applying it in the wrong spot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just `ctrl` drag your label to the image view and select `Center Horizontally` and then select the label and on the right side, click the `Edit` button on the `Aligh Center Y to` constraint and set the multiplier to 1.8~2.0 in your case.

Comment: This did it. I had to use 1.68 for the multiplier but this is exactly the solution. Thanks @j-wang!

Answer (score 0):

Control drag from the label to the image and you will get a list of constraint options. Select the "Center Vertically" and "Center Horizontally" options. Then the label will be constrained to the center of the image like you want. It works. See the attached images; I did it on an iPhone 6s as well as an iPad Pro just to show that it will scale with any size. [image: Example Image on iPad Pro][image: Example Image on iPhone 6s][image: Command Drag from Label to ImageView Options]

Comment: That will work if I turn those circles into 3 separate images, which is likely what I will do. Right now they are all part of 1 "background" image that is made up of the blue color with the white circles. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ya, that's probably best. If you were set on not separating them, you could set the labels to have centered text and then give them all equal widths and constrain them to their sides (i.e. "|-0-(label1)-0-(lable2)-0-(label3)-0-|") and then center them vertically like mentioned above. That is kind of dangerous though because it assumes the images are centered and exactly 1/3 width of the superView; but if that is the case, then it will work:)

Comment: Actually, you mentioned you already figured out the centering horizontally, so ignore my suggestion in the above comment. You still want to center each of the labels vertically to the imageView like mentioned above. They will all just be centered vertically to the same image instead of three separate images like I did.

Comment: Yup, it worked out perfectly. I still think in the future it would be easier to slice up the UI like the very first suggestion so I'll have to remember that moving forward. Thanks for the help!