# How do you align multiple views with background image elements using auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Here is the scenario: I have a background image with 3 circles and 3 horizontal lines, above the circles I have 3 views in the shape of rectangles. I want the rectangles to be directly above the circles and roughly as wide as the circles as well as the same height across all iPhones and iPads (from the first horizontal bar to the top margin). I built a sample in Sketch as a visual aid. Any help would be much appreciated!
[visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtwcv.png)

The specific issue I'm having with the constraints I've tried is that the top stays pinned to the top margin but the bottom constraint doesn't really scale with the different iPhone sizes. Here is another screen capture.
[bottom height issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2P44.png)
The bottom constraint I'm using is a Vertical Space Constraint with the first item as the bottom of the view with an equal relation to the bottom of the rectangle and it's an equal 283 points. I understand why it *won't* work, 283 from the bottom just doesn't end up in the same spot on all 3 devices, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question.  Post what you have tried and the problem you are facing with your code and someone will help you.  As far as the constraints... You can pin constraints of objects to be equal height and equal width, maybe you should go over an auto layout tutorial then come back with a problem you are facing after you have tried something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I updated my post with a better description of what I'm trying to do and what isn't working. I hope that helps explain things. I want the rectangles to be equal width, but the height of them is driven buy a variable in code so I want them to equal the height of that value with a minimum height of 0 and maximum height of whatever the distance is between that first line and the top of the margin so all 3 will constantly be un-equal heights, if that makes sense.

Please let me know what other info is missing that may help!

Comment: @BradW.Allen It's you again:). I thought this would be the same issue as the one you encounter [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641944/what-do-you-apply-auto-layout-constraints-to-line-up-labels-with-background-imag/35642149#35642149)?

Comment: Yup it's me again. ;) I tried to apply the same logic as in the other post but I don't think it will work (I could be wrong...). The size of the labels in the other post should all be equal to one another, but in this scenario, the size will be determined by a value in code, and I only (think) I need to apply the top and bottom constraints. This is where I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @J.Wang, am I providing enough information? I agree with MSU_Bulldog that my original post seemed like I hadn't even tried yet. I've been messing with it all day today and can't get it to do what I want!

Comment: @BradW.Allen From the visual aid you gave, I thought these three rectangles would have the same height?

Comment: Yeah I can see why... that will be their maximum height (between that horizontal grey line and the top of the view) and their minimum height would be zero. Each rectangle will be fed a different value (based on accelerometer data) and so the height of each one will be different. The image in the background is a graph.

Comment: @BradW.Allen Remember to @ me otherwise I can't receive the message.:P. So what you're trying to do is, correct me if I'm wrong, dynamically set the height of these rectangles and expecting them to scale automatically on different devices. For example, if at one time, you set the height of the rect to be `100` on iPhone 5 and you want the `100` to be scaled automatically to, let's say `150` on iPhone 6 Plus. Is this right?

Comment: @J.Wang yes, I think you've got it. Sorry about the missing the @, I thought you'd see it by just replying. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BradW.Allen Okay, let's solve this. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @J.Wang you rock brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically when you change the height of the rect you need to consider the height of the whole view. You would want to have a design height of screen, for instance, I choose 600 here. So I'd use the following function to calculate the actual height I want for the current device.

```
    func actualHeight(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return height / 600 * view.bounds.height
    }
```

So when you want to set the height of the rect to 100 out of 600, I'd use `actualHeight(100)` instead.

Remember if you've already set the height constraint in the interface builder, it wouldn't work by setting the height of the view directly. One way to do is by cooperating with the constaints. You'd have to create an outlet for the height constraints and change the `constant` property of the constraint.

I got this image online, but it shows how to create an outlet for the constraint.

[image]

So you'd have a `IBOutlet`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstaint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And you'll set the height like this:

```
heightConstaint.constant = actualHeight(400)
```

---

If you don't like the height constaint method, you can use transform:

```
// Scale the height by 1.1.
rect.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.1)
```

As long as your height constaint is set correctly in the IB, this will scale it on whatever devices.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll give it a shot tonight when I get home and get back to you.

Comment: This worked. We ended up with a combo approach though of using your suggestion and taking the background image and slicing it up into 4 pieces (like what was suggested in my previous question) which really helped.

Thanks again for the help!